# How to add new columns to CSVs with the same text in all lines

Tags: bash, awk, csv

This a sample of my input file:

```
22/12/1999,conductivity,42,uS/cm
06/01/2000,conductivity,22,uS/cm
26/01/2000,conductivity,26,uS/cm
09/02/2000,conductivity,32,uS/cm
23/02/2000,conductivity,33,uS/cm
```

I would like to reformat it so that it matches another database. The first column needs to say `COMPTON` in all lines, a sixth needs to say `PRECIPITATION`, and a seventh `NOT APPLICABLE`.

I probably need to use some `awk` function but am unsure.

Comment: Nicola, do you tried in this way? Do you have had some problem? https://askubuntu.com/a/1193544/796708

Comment: Nicola if it works, please choose it as the right answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) you can run

```
mlr --csv -N put '$a="COMPTON";$b="PRECIPITATION";$c="NOT APPLICABLE"' then reorder -f a  input.csv
```

to have

```
+---------+------------+--------------+----+-------+---------------+----------------+
| COMPTON | 22/12/1999 | conductivity | 42 | uS/cm | PRECIPITATION | NOT APPLICABLE |
| COMPTON | 06/01/2000 | conductivity | 22 | uS/cm | PRECIPITATION | NOT APPLICABLE |
| COMPTON | 26/01/2000 | conductivity | 26 | uS/cm | PRECIPITATION | NOT APPLICABLE |
| COMPTON | 09/02/2000 | conductivity | 32 | uS/cm | PRECIPITATION | NOT APPLICABLE |
| COMPTON | 23/02/2000 | conductivity | 33 | uS/cm | PRECIPITATION | NOT APPLICABLE |
+---------+------------+--------------+----+-------+---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, but shouldn't "PRECIPITATION" be $f= and "NOT APPLICABLE" be $g= ? A quarter hour of reading the Miller FAQ and examples hasn't shown me examples of using `put` for text...

Comment: No, the name is not important for the order. The field names could be what you want

Comment: I'm puzzled by the order. Looks like, since you are using _$b=_ for "PRECIPITATION", how does that not end up in the second column? Since you use _$c=_ for "NOT APPLICABLE", how does it not end up in the third column?

Comment: The order and the name of the fields are not related. I start from the order of the input file - column 1, 2, 3 and 4 - then I add the fields a, b and c, that become  the fifth, the sixth and the seventh fields. And at the end I move the fifth one (a) at start, using the verb `reorder`

Comment: Aha! TY very much!